# Sphinx autodoc for python module doesn't show module doc on readthedocs

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I've written and documented a python module which I want to host on ReadTheDocs. I'm using sphinx to generate the docs, and for some reason, even though it works locally, ReadTheDocs does not render the docstrings I've included in the code.

I'm including a link to the repo and other relevant files here:

- [Repo](https://gitlab.com/omazhary/SamRand)
- [docs folder](https://gitlab.com/omazhary/SamRand/-/tree/master/docs)
- [conf.py](https://gitlab.com/omazhary/SamRand/-/blob/master/docs/conf.py)
- [.readthedocs.yml](https://gitlab.com/omazhary/SamRand/-/blob/master/.readthedocs.yml)

I've come across several threads that proposed solutions, including mocking (which I've included in the conf.py file). For some reason, none of them work. I can't help but feel I'm missing something basic. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's against the site rules to ask a question where the code necessary to reproduce the problem is hosted in an external source. The reason is that if the code in the external sources ever becomes unavailable both the question and the answers loose their value. So please edit the question to include the necessary code to reproduce the problem in the body of the question.

Comment: Most likely, you need to install dependencies on RTD that you already installed locally. See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#my-documentation-requires-additional-dependencies